# Athena Database Level Access Control

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-athena

I have created two databases D1 and D2 in the same region on Amazon Athena. I want to limit users' access to these databases. I would like D1 to be listed only for user U1. In fact, U1 should not even be aware that there is another database (D2).

How can I set database-level access control for Athena?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define fine-grained access to the AWS glue data catalog by using the resource-level permissions in IAM policies. fine-grained controls apply at the database/table level.

For example, the following IAM policy:

```
{
"Effect": "Allow",
 "Action": [
   "glue:GetDatabase", 
   "glue:CreateDatabase"
],
"Resource": [
  "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:123456789012:catalog",
  "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:123456789012:database/default"
]
}
```

Will only grant access to the 'default' table inside 'database' db (and for the data catalog of course)

For more information [see aws glue data catalog fine-grained access documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/fine-grained-access-to-glue-resources.html) 
For the IAM policies doc, click [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html)

Comment: I have created tables directly in Athena without using Glue. It wouldn't work, would it?

Comment: It’ll work. Every database you create through Athena is auto added to the glue data catalog. Actually, that’s where your table’s metadata is stored.